# Float not returning decimal when dividing

Tags: android

I am dividing 2 numbers and want to return a decimal when appropriate. But it is returning whole number on everything.

```
float temp = (twoMileInSeconds - 774) / 6;
timeIndex = (int)Math.floor(temp);

debug1.setText("Before rounding: " + temp);
debug2.setText("After rounding: " + timeindex);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data type is 'twomileinsecods' ? If its int, then that is the problem... or maybe if you put 6.0 instead of 6.

To ensure that the division taking place to the right of the equals sign results in a float, make sure all data types on the right are already floats.  The problem is that it's casting to float AFTER the division has already taken place.

Comment: twoMileInSeconds is an int. Should it be float?

Comment: yeah changed twoMileInSeconds to float and now it's showing the correct decimal. Thanks!

Comment: Can i get get a ramrod thumbs up?

Comment: Yeah I was waiting for the timer to run out. Sorry. And thanks for the info. Had me baffled.

Answer (score 1):

If you will type cast to float then also it will work perfectly as you have taken a variable twoMileInSeconds and it can be integer as well so you can go for this approach as well.

```
float temp = (float) (twoMileInSeconds - 774) / 6;
        int timeIndex = (int)Math.floor(temp);
```